# Disable a "Back Button" once there is no web site to get back to

Tags: c#, button, web, browser, back

I'm basically learning C# and made myself a simple web browser and added "back" and "forward" buttons to navigate through sites that I opened. Well the thing is, I can't figure out how to disable them if there are no more sites to get back to.

I tried to put this simple code into my form's constructor, but it seems like it does not have any affect...

```
        if (webBrowser1.CanGoBack == false)
        {
            backButton.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            backButton.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: If this goes in the form's *constructor* then it's only going to execute once, when the form is constructed.  I imagine you'd want to perform this check any time a navigation event is performed on the web browser control, no?

Answer (score 0):

The code in Constructor would be only called once. So, it would be better if you place the code else where in your code where the code can be called multiple times. Possibly, firing on events or any custom button you have on your form controls.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I would say that the code needs to be executed every time the browser navigates back rather than when the form is initialized, also the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.cangoback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article does show a better method of setting this and offers some explanation for you on the cangoback method.

Answer (score 0):

So programs need to be told not only what to do, but when to do things. Putting the Enable/Disable logic in the constructor is saying "When the form loads, check this and enable/disable it."

But once you're passed the constructor, nothing is telling it when to change it's enable/disable state.

Try using [Event Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx) to let your program know "Hey, I need to update the enabled state of these buttons"

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for help!
Putting my code into an event made a job...

```
    private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        comboBox1.Text = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();

        if (webBrowser1.CanGoBack == false)
        {
            backButton.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            backButton.Enabled = true;
        }


        if (webBrowser1.CanGoForward == false)
        {
            forwardButton.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            forwardButton.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```